# How can you update an iOS Simulator deployment target using Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, appauth, deployment-target

Does anyone know how to update the Simulator deployment target using SwiftPM? Based on my research I have not found any good solution other and reimplement a new package. I found and know how to update the minimum targets using CocoaPods but not SPM. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

For greater context, the package I am working with and attempting to change is for AppAuth for iOS -> https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/master/README.md

My current simulator deployment target is set to 8.0 but the supported deployment target is between 9.0 to 14.5.99. I don't know how to change the simulator deployment target while using SwiftPM. The current build target overall is set to 14.0. The code snippet below is the warning I am getting when I build the project.

```
The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of the supported deployment target version is 9.0 to 14.5.99.
```

[Deployment Warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Com.png)

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. More specifically, what Package is causing the issue? What's the deployment target of your package? What's your project's deployment target?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing you can do if it's a dependency you don't own. The issue is that the minimum iOS version supported by Xcode 12 is iOS 9. The third party you are referring is setting the [minimum compatible version to iOS 8](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/master/Package.swift#L27) so unless you ask the developer to bump it to iOS 9 or fork it and maintain it yourself, you will have to live with those warnings.

Please refer [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/minimum-ios-version-xcode-12-and-build-warnings/40224) for more details.